# PHP CodeIgniter [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-upload

In PHP CodeIgniter when try to upload an image, it shows an error
[an error occurred while processing this directive]:

```
Security Alert

The file you are uploading was rejected by the server.  
It probably contents viruses or trojans that can damage your website.  

Do not attempt to upload it again as your IP address may be blocked.
```

What is this?

Comment: What is the file name/extension?

Comment: Is this a core CodeIgniter feature? I doubt the framework on its own contains a virus scanner!

Comment: Try to upload another file to server. Does it work?

Comment: @halfer Mant times this error occur due to mod_security function enable on linux server. So contact your server administrator for disable mod_security function...×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes